# If two keystore files have the same password, can it be figured out?

Tags: encryption

If two different keystore files have the same password, can it be figured out?

Suppose I publish to the internet two keystore files corresponding to two different addresses. The files have the same password. Given some amount of transactions on each one, can the password be uncovered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Passwords cannot be derived from transactions. Passwords encrypt your private keys. Two different keystore files have 2 different private keys and their encryption by the same password results in 2 very different encrypted keys.